# how to solve Encoding error in using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am facing the encoding error how to fix that this is error File `"F:\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 117-122: character maps to <undefined>`   bacillay I having encoding error in these line `product_url = 'https://' + url['MARKETPLACE'] + '/dp/' + url['ASIN']`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd




df_urls = pd.read_csv('D:/selenium/inputs/amazone-asin.csv')
list_dicts_urls =df_urls.to_dict('records')

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

for url in list_dicts_urls:
    product_url = 'https://' + url['MARKETPLACE'] + '/dp/' + url['ASIN']
    driver.get(product_url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#sp-cc-accept"))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    item = dict()
    try:
        about_this_item_list = []
        about_this_item_divs = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ".//div[@id='featurebullets_feature_div']//ul//li//span")))
        for div in about_this_item_divs:
            about_this_dict = dict()
            about_this_dict['about_this_item'] = div.text
            about_this_item_list.append(about_this_dict)
        item['about_this_item'] = about_this_item_list
    except:
        item['about_this_item'] = ''
    
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enforce `utf-8` throughout the program.

```py
df_urls = pd.read_csv('D:/selenium/inputs/amazone-asin.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

and see if the data file is corrupted.